# Renaming sheets in Excel using Python; referencing cell value for sheet name

Tags: python, excel-2010

I have been working on a project using Python to build a program that simplifies changes to be made in Microsoft Excel. I am attempting to loop through a workbook to rename all of the sheets. The main difference my problem has from what I have read is that I am renaming the sheets based on a value in a cell using the following code:

```
"""Loop through each worksheet and rename the sheet using a value from the sheet."""
for i in wb:
    ws = wb.active
    c = ws['A1']
    ws.title = c + (i + 1)
    print(sheet.title)
```

If someone could clarify what the issue is I would greatly appreciate your assistance. I received the following error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Que\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\child.py", line 93, in title
    m = INVALID_TITLE_REGEX.search(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I am using Powershell interactive mode to test each piece of code. Please understand I am attempting to access a value in a cell and have made several attempts to change the code to reflect my objective. Your insight and observations are appreciated.

Comment: Should not you use the value of c (c.value) instead of the cell itself?

Comment: Hi holypriest! You are on to something! I change the code based on your recommendation and I received the following:  for i in wb:  ws = wb.active  c = ws['A1']  ws.title = c.value  print(ws.title)  Marque  Marque

Comment: You are looping through the sheets, why are you getting the active one all the times?

Comment: You have my name! The code iterated over the first sheet. Can we discuss why the program skipped the first sheet?

Comment: Does my answer below solve your problem? If you want to change the names of all your sheets, you should not get the active sheet all the time, but the one you got from the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code below will solve the problem:

```
for sheet in wb:
    sheet_name = sheet.title
    first_cell_value = str(sheet['A1'].value)
    sheet.title = first_cell_value + sheet_name + "1"
    print(sheet.title)
```

This way you are:

- looping through all the sheets on your workbook;
- getting their names;
- getting the value of their first cells (A1) as a string;
- changing their names to `first_cell_value + sheet_name + "1"`;
- printing their new names

The error report you are getting is because you are trying to use the cell itself (`c`) instead of the value inside of it (`c.value`) to rename your worksheet, and the cell itself is not a string/byte-like object.

Comment: for sheet in wb:
...     sheet_name = sheet.title
...     first_cell_value = str(sheet['A1'].value)
...     ws.title = first_cell_value + sheet_name
...     print(sheet_name)
...
Test
125Test

Comment: I received the above results: Test 125Test. The code doesn't seem to be iterating through the sheets correctly.

Comment: You have clarified somethings for me though. I appreciate!

Comment: I tried the code and it worked as expected. Iterated over all the sheets and renamed them using the rule `first_cell_value + sheet_name + "1"`. Try the command `wb.sheetnames` to see if all the sheets show up. These are the sheets you will get through the iteration process.

Comment: Thank you for your support! After much toil on my part, and with your support, I produced a solution. I understand a little better how the loop works in this environment: Marque [10:31 PM]
for sheet in wb:
...     first_cell_value = str(sheet['A1'].value)
...     sheet.title = first_cell_value
...     print(sheet.title)

Comment: I am happy to help. Please mark my answer as accepted, if you found it helpful. Just click the arrow up (above the zero) and then the checkmark (below the arrow down)